# How to add title/Pager ViewPagerIndicator on the left of the title/pager that already exists?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I get a problem when adding Title viewpagerindicator . I can just only add Title on the right course.
ex :

Title already exists :

**Title 1 | Title 2 | Title 3**

after add on Right :

**Title 1 | Title 2 | Title 3 | Title Right 1  | Title Right 2**
and this my code:

```
        mAdapter = new TestFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // add Title when create activity
        mAdapter.addTitle("Title 1");
        mAdapter.addTitle("Title 2");       
        mAdapter.addTitle("Title 3");

        mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        indicator = (TitlePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        indicator.setViewPager(mPager);
        indicator.setFooterIndicatorStyle(IndicatorStyle.Triangle);

        //add Title on Right
        AddRightTitle_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View view) {    
             mAdapter.addTitle("Title Right 1");    
             mAdapter.addTitle("Title Right 2");
           }
        });

       //add Title on Left
        AddLeftTitle_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View view) {    
             // how the code ?

           }
        });
```

this the FragmentAdapter

```
public class TestFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    ArrayList<String> TITLE = new ArrayList<String>();

    public TestFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {

        super(fm);
    }

    public void addTitle(String title){
        TITLE.add(title);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return TestFragment.newInstance(TITLE.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return TITLE.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getPageTitle(int position) {
         return TITLE.get(position);
    }


    public boolean isExitsPage(String Title){

        return TITLE.contains(Title);
    }

}
```

then how to add Title on the left like this ? :

**Title Left 2 | Title Left 1 | Title 1 | Title 2 | Title 3 | Title Right 1  | Title Right 2**

Sorry For My English

Answer (score 0):

you can add a method in TestFragmentAdapter.

`public void addTitle(String title,int position){
        TITLE.add(position,title);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }`

if you want to add title in left,just do 
`addTitle(0,title_left)`

I hope i can help you!Sorry For My English ;)